# Simple binary subtraction

Tags: binary

$$101110 - 110111$$

Did the 2's complment and cannot get to the answer. The answer is apparently 
$$-1001$$

I did 2's complment on the $$110111$$
and performed addition but did not get to the answer.
But I heard that I have to "zero-fill" before i do it or something

Comment: Did you write the result correctly (as decimal)?

Comment: As decimal, it's impossible.  Did you mean binary $-1001$? That's what I get, binary, i.e., in decimal terms $-9_{10}$

Comment: Are you sure the answer is $-1004$? Because if the answer is supposed to be in binary, you can't have a $4$ digit in the answer. Only $0$s and $1$s are allowed.

Comment: The answer can't be $-1004$ in decimal either, because 
$101110$ is even and $110111$ is odd.

Comment: Sorry, edited. -1001

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$101110 - 110111 = 101110 + 001001 = 110111$$ with $110111$ being in two's complement (since it has a leading $1$, hence, equivalent to binary $-001001 \; = \;-1001$

The trick I use to go back and forth from two's complement is to switch ALL digits (reverse $1\to 0, 0 \to 1$, then add one bit $1$ ($+000001$ in this case)

Comment: How come when i two's complement 110111 and do addition it does not give me your answer?

Comment: do you get two's complement of 110111 = 001001?

Comment: I take 110111, replace all 1's with 0's, all zero's with 1's, and add one bit: step 1: $110111 \to 001000$. Second step: $001000 + 000001 = 001001$. Then add $001001$ to 101110, getting  110111. But the leading $1$ indicates it's negative in two's complement, so we need to perform the two's complement (in reverse, exact same procedure to get it's magnitude), but prefixing it with $-$ sign: $110111\to 001000 + 1 \to -1001$

Comment: So that's what I missed. I got halfway basically. I didn't know that you have to perform two's complement twice

Comment: So if there is a leading one after binary subtraction using 2s complement, you have to do 2s complmenent again?

Comment: Yes, the leading one tells means you need to perform the two's complement again, exactly! Got it?

Comment: So, no leading 0, it's fine as it is. Leading 1, perform 2s complement again?

Comment: Yes, exactly, but with the leading $1$, remember to prefix with a negative sign after doing two's complement again.

Comment: Got ya. Thanks for the great explanation.

Comment: You're welcome, Aaron!

Answer (score 2):

Convert the subtacthend to two's complement and add:

101110−110111 = 101110 + 001001 = 110111

Now, we have a 1-bit as the MSB, telling us that this is a negative number in 2's complement form, so take the two's complement and keep the negative sign.

Thus, we have ( - 001000 + 1 ) = -1001.

Comment: +1 Hmmm...I think I remember this question. Rings a bell...;-)

Comment: Yeah - I have forgotten about 100000 dollars worth of my formal education! :-) Now I understand what the real world does to a person!

Answer (score 1):

Well, when I have to substract a bigger number from a smaller one I just flip over the numbers , make the substraction and change sign, say:

$$12-34 =-(34-12)=-22$$

Why not do the same here? Remember: in binary, $\,1-1=0\;,\;1-0=1\;,\;\,0-1=1$...**and** we carry one, etc. , so:

$$110111-101110 \Longrightarrow\begin{cases}110111\\-\\101110\\........\\001001\end{cases}$$

and now change sign: $\, 101110-110111 =-1001\,$ , and in decimal: $\,46-55=-9\,$

Comment: Nice Don. This one doesn't have .... at the end. +1 :D

Comment: Hehe...indeed it doesn't @BabakS. since the OP alreadu knew the answer so it was only a matter of showing him my idea.

Answer (score 0):

$110111$ is correct after performing the addition. The leftmost bit is a $1$, indicating that it's a negative number. Use the two's complement on $110111$ to get $001001$, then remove the leading $0$s and add the negative to get $-1001$.